# Positive polynomial conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials

Suppose we have a polynomial $p$

$$
p = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots+a_Nx^N = \sum_{i=0}^Na_ix^i.
$$

what is the sufficient and necessary condition of $\{a_i:i=0,1,\dots, N\}$ such that $p$ is always positive for all $x\in(0, +\infty)$

(does such sufficient and necessary conditions even exist?)

In other words: what kind of (and necessary) coefficients could make the polynomial always positive on the right side of $\mathbb{R}?$

*Guess: what about let $\xi_k$ be all of the roots of $\frac{dp}{dx}=0$, and the condition is $p(\xi_k)$ are all positive, and $a_N>0$?*

Comment: Why the RHS lost its $a_i$s?

Comment: @user10354138 sry, edited.

Comment: There is no real need for the denominators $i!$, you can very well work with the coefficients $b_i=a_i/i!$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, indeed. Edited.

Comment: Your guess involved roost and it is not completely in terms of the coefficients. In terms of roots a N and S condition is that all the roots are negative. But I don't know if this can be written in terms of the coefficients.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to write out an explicit condition in terms of any general $a_i$ and $N$. The only conditions, as far a I can think, is that the value of $p$ at all the roots of $\frac{dp}{dx}$ is positive. And this can't be expressed explicitly as polynomials of degree $5$ and higher do not have a general solution in radicals (according to the Abel-Ruffini Theorem).

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition involving the derivative is that the polynomial has a positive constant term, and evaluates to positive at every positive root of the first derivative. This is not very helpful.

Comment: What you want to find the maximum root and to have the function always increasing after that root. No idea how to accomplish this in general terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition uses [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).  You want $a_N > 0$ and $V(0) = V(\infty)$,  where $V(x)$ is the number of sign changes of the Sturm sequence of $p$ at $x$.

Comment: so, basically, the polynomial has to have no roots on $(0, +\infty)$, and $a_N>0$

Comment: May I further ask, if using the polynomial in my question, are there any general expression for the Sturm's sequence in terms of those coefficients?

Comment: $p_0 = p = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$, $p_1 = p' = \sum_{i=1}^n i a_i x^{i-1}$, 
$p_{i+1} = - \text{rem}(p_{i-1}, p_i)$: its coefficients are rational functions of the coefficients of $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$, but I don't know of a general expression.